# Masonry not working on loading… Elements don't re-align themselves until I resize the window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, masonry

Hello all i am using Masonry layout for my web, but i am facing a problem that masonry item did not arrange itself until i resize my browser windows.after resizing browser windows it arrange.

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row"> 
    <!-- STRATEGIES -->

        <div class="col-sm-4 child-item clearfix">
            <div class="group-a">
                <div class="title-a title" style="display: none;">
                    <h3><?php echo $groupa; ?></h3>
                </div><!-- title -->

                <div class="content-a content" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div id="RIG8A" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <img src="../assets/images/compass.jpg">
                            </div><!-- col -->
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <h4><?php echo $rig8a_content; ?></h4>
                                <div id="pu-icon">
                                    <img id="rig8a_p" src="../assets/icon/pu_icon_faded.png">
                                    <img id="rig8a_s" src="../assets/icon/su_icon_faded.png">
                                </div><!-- pu-icon -->
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- RIG8A -->
```

```
<script>$(window).on('load',function() {$('#container').masonry({itemSelector: '.child-item', columnWidth: '.child-item',percentPosition: true});});</script>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add more information? For example, what is your code?

Comment: my code i too long and cannot arrange here.if it is possible then i will send you link where problem exist.

Comment: You should create a minimal code representing your problem. Without any code we cannot find a solution to your problem.

Comment: you could copy paste it in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i added code please  check out html

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(window).on('load',function(){
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.child-item', // use a separate class for itemSelector, other than .col-
  columnWidth: '.child-item',
  percentPosition: true
});

});


</script>

Comment: this is javascript

Comment: @blackhat: Code does not belong in comments. Please [edit] your javascript into the post.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: Perhaps you should take the advice @c00L left you. Use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen) to make something that shows the issue you're having, then post a link to it here.